# Problem in Perl module LWP::Protocol::http

Tags: perl, http

I have a perl script on a web server that basically relays a Post to another URL.
It has been working fine for several months but suddenly now gives an error.
It works OK on a different webserver.
I have a simplified script that shows the problem, although I have redacted the actual target url and parameters below.
I have updated the Perl modules, but to no effect.
It consistently gives the error message:

```
read failed: at /data04/cdc/perl5/lib/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 382.
```

The line in question in http.pm is

```
my $n = $socket->sysread($buf, 1024, length($buf));
unless (defined $n) {
    die "read failed: $!" unless  $!{EINTR} || $!{EWOULDBLOCK} || $!{EAGAIN};
```

I don't know how to go about solving this problem. The hosting company just tell me it is a problem with the 3rd party LWP script which they cannot help me with.

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://XXXX/YYYY/';

my @lmargs;
push @lmargs, 'p1', 'v1';
push @lmargs, 'p2', 'v2';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post( $url, \@lmargs);

my $resp = $response->decoded_content();

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

print "<html> <head>\n";
print "<title>Hello, world!</title>";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<h1>Test 2</h1>\n";
if (! defined $response) { print "<br>No response defined<br>"; }
elsif (! defined $resp)  { print "<br>No decoded response defined<br>"; }
else                     { print "<br>decoded response=$resp<br>"; }

print "</body> </html>\n";

exit;
```

Comment: Given that you are using a `https://` URL the result of `sysread` comes from IO::Socket::SSL. Please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug6 script.pl` and provide the output in the question.

Comment: Steffen, thanks but I only have the facility to upload scripts to the server in question. What do I need to add to my script to produce the debug information?

Comment: add `use IO::Socket::SSL 'debug6';` to the script, but better before including LWP::UserAgent.

Comment: Adding that line didn't produce any more information, but it prompted me to reinstall IO::Socket::SSL. This reported an error in another part of http.pm. So I tried re-installing all modules - and it is now working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by re-installing all of the Perl Modules on our section of the server. Both the hosting company and I have no idea why this was necessary. There were apparently no updates or maintenance issues prior to the script stopping working.

Comment: There might have been updates to the server you are trying to access, which required a more modern version of what you were using. Hard to tell without knowing what versions you were running before and what the requirements of the server you've tried to reach are.